# Do the hypnotic moths in these works share a common origin?

Tags: inspiration, bas-lag, the-worst-witch

In *The Worst Witch* TV series (2017), there's a creature called a hypnapillon. It's a moth, described as feeding off of people's "minds, fears, imagination," and it hypnotizes its prey with patterns on its wings, leaving them in a mindless state.

This struck me as extremely similar to the slake-moths from the Bas-Lag Cycle by China Mieville, though obviously the tone and presentation is very different between the two works.

Do both these creatures have a common origin in some mythological or earlier fictional work? Or even some actual moth species that I'm unaware of?

Comment: _Empire in Black and Gold_ by Adrian Tchaikovsky has _Moth Kinden_ with similar features. It was written in 2008, though, well after Perdido Street Station.

Comment: I feel like I've seen moths associated with hypnotism and dreams elsewhere, but I can't think of where exactly

Comment: @Jack In Susan Cooper's book "Silver on the tree", she mentions plume moths. "White plume moths. There's an old saying, that they carry memories away."